# Can a proper subgroup of the multiplicative group of a finite field form an arithmetic progression.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

To rule out special cases, here the proper subgroup should not be $1$, and the length of arithmetic progression is finite and at least $3$. If we can permute a subgroup to form an AP, the it also meets the requirement.
Arithmetic progression in this context is just $\{a+nd| n\in \mathbb{N}， n\le N\}\subset \mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is the given finite field. I tried some cases like $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$, and didn't find any.
So my question is whether we have infinitely many finite fields qualified or the proposition is generally false?

Comment: My point is that where the group is cyclic of even order, there will always be a subgroup of order $2$. [My last comment, which I have deleted was misleading, I think]

Comment: I think the expectation is that this should be very rare.  There is a growing body of work on the “sum-product phenomenon”, which quantifies the idea that the same cannot both have a lot of additive structure and a lot of multiplicative structure at the same time.  A lot of effort has been dedicated to bounding $|A+A|$ versus $|A\cdot A|$, and in the finite field setting these are a little odd to talk about once $A$ is significantly larger than $\sqrt{n}$.    Still, your question is specific enough that I am hopeful it admits a clever solution.

Comment: I see now how my previous (now deleted) answer is wrong. Thinking about that some more I found the following interesting example in a ring that is not a field: $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$. The set $\{1, 7, 4\}$ is an arithmetic progression AND a multiplicative subgroup in this ring AND it has cardinality greater than 2 (namely: 3). If such examples can also be found in fields, I don't know.

Comment: @Vincent Great example!

Comment: @user132603 Another trivial category to exclude: the non-zero part of the prime subfield of any finite field of non-prime order $GF(p^r)$ always forms the arithmetic progression $1,2,\ldots,p-1$.  This construction obviously only makes sense for $p>3$.  Are you primarily interested in prime-sized finite fields?

Comment: @ErickWong I was also contemplating a bounty for this, but you beat me to it. If you something else that is also exemplary, feel free to bring it up in [the Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive).

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen! I was not familiar with this discussion board until now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only such progressions are the "obvious" ones, namely:

$$S = \{1\}, \quad \{-1,1\}  \ \text{when $\mathrm{char}(k) > 2$}, \quad \{1,2,3,4,\ldots,p-1\}.$$

The first coincides with the last when $\mathrm{char}(k) = 2$, and the second coincides with the last when $\mathrm{char}(k) = 3$.

Let $p$ denote the characteristic of $k$, let $n$ denote the length of the subgroup/arithmetic progression $S$, and let $q = |k|$. The multiplicative subgroup $k^{\times}$ of a finite field is cyclic, so if $|S| = n$, then

$$S = \{1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\ldots,\zeta^{n-1}\}$$

where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity.

**Some Reductions:** If $k$ has characteristic $p$, then in any arithmetic progression $a, a+d,a+2d,\ldots$, the initial term $a$ and the $p+1$st term $a+pd=a$ coincide, and thus $n = |S| \le p$. Moreover, the order $|S|$ divides the order of $k^{\times}$ which is $q-1$ where $q$ a power of $p$. Thus $(n,p) = 1$, and hence $n < p$. It follows that if $p = 2$ then $n = 1$ and so $S = \{1\}$, and if $p = 3$ then either $n = 1$ and $S = \{1\}$ or $n = 2$ and $S = \{1,-1\}$.

**The argument:** We may assume that $p > 3$, $2 < n \le p - 1$, and $(n,p) = 1$.
Suppose that the common difference of the arithmetic progression is $d \in k$. Since $1 \in S$, the set $S$ also must have the form:

$$S = \{1+id \ | \ i \in [-a,n-1-a]\}$$

for some $0 \le a \le n-1$. But now we find that
$$\sum_{x \in S} x = \sum_{i=-a}^{n-1-a} 1 + i d
= \frac{n(2-d-2ad+dn)}{2}.$$

but we also have

$$\sum_{x \in S} x = 1 + \zeta + \ldots + \zeta^{n-1} = \frac{\zeta^n-1}{\zeta - 1} = 0$$

since $\zeta^n = 1$. From these two evaluations we deduce (noting that $n \ne 0$ because $(n,p) = 1$) that

$$(1+2a-n)d = 2.$$

Since $k$ has characteristic different from $2$, it follows that $d$ and $(1+2a-n)$ are both units, and hence that

$$d = \frac{2}{1+2a-n}$$

But now we compute that

$$\sum_{x \in S} x^2 = 1 + \zeta^2 + \ldots + \zeta^{2(n-1)} = \frac{\zeta^{2n} - 1}{\zeta^2 - 1} = 0$$

where we assume that $n > 2$ so $\zeta^2 - 1 \ne 0$, and

$$\sum_{x \in S} x^2 =  \sum_{n=-a}^{n-1-a} (1 + i d)^2
= \frac{n (n^2 - 1)}{3 (1 + 2 a - n)^2},$$

where we use that $k$ has characteristic $p > 3$ so there are no issues with the RHS. Now combining these two formulae, we deduce that $n(n+1)(n-1) = 0$. Since $1< n < p$ and $p$ is prime, this can happen only when $n = p-1$. The elements of order $p-1$ in $k$ are precisely the non-zero roots of $x^p - x = 0$, or equivalently the primitive subfield $\mathbf{F}_p$. Thus we have found all such examples.

Comment: Very nice!  This uses character orthogonality in an essential way so that you extract a lot of power out of the subgroup requirement.

Comment: Nice. In summary, we just consider the two sums in two ways.

Comment: Nice, indeed. It may be worth pointing out that if $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ is a list of elements of the group $G$ in an arithmetic progression with increment $d$, then $1,x_1^{-1}x_2,x_1^{-1}x_3,\ldots,x_1^{-1}x_n$ is another list of elements of the group $G$ in an arithmetic progression with increment $x_1^{-1}d$. This means that without loss of generality you can assume that the AP starts from $1$. In other words, you can assume that $a=0$. I don't know if this simplifies the calculations enough to make it worth your while to edit the post.